# Wordpress getting updated meta for multiple posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working with wp updating meta values.In my codes here is the main function :

```
$get_post_ids = array();
$get_post_ids[] = $_REQUEST['ids'];

foreach ($get_post_ids as $post_id) {
  $meta_value = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'resturent_featured', true );
  if( $meta_value == 'yes' ){
     $new_value = update_post_meta( $post_id, 'resturent_featured', 'no' );
  }else{
     $new_value = update_post_meta( $post_id, 'resturent_featured', 'yes' );
  }
}
```

Its working when i select one post.but not working when selecting multiple posts.

Comment: Give an example of how the array `$get_post_ids` looks in both cases, i.e. when it works and when it doesn't work. Also include a better description of what fails - i.e. do you get an error, or is the meta information not update (and if so, how did you find out).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something might be wrong here.If you `$get_post_ids[]` is a array with a key and a value with comma separated then it must be `$_REQUEST['ids']` comma separated.Then you have to use this way:

```
$get_post_ids = $_REQUEST['ids'];
$get_post_ids = explode(',', $get_post_ids);
```